# Unhandled promise rejection error in passport.authenticate() when using throw error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, custom-error-handling

I am trying to send out the occurred authentification error as a Node.js/Express JSON response API.

My code:

```
console.log("LOGIN USER...");
  try {
    let errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) throw { code: 400, message: errors }
    let authopt = { usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password' };
    passport.authenticate('local', authopt, (err, user, info) => {
      if (err || !user) {
        console.log("ERROR IS PASSING FROM HERE.");
        throw { code: 500, message: err }
      }
      else {
        const token = user.generateJWT();
        return res.status(200).json({
          "jwtToken": token,
        });
      }
    })(req, res, next)
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(error.code || 500).send(error.message || "Unknown internal server error ! .");
  }
```

After endpoint call, the message **'ERROR IS PASSING FROM HERE.'** is showing up in my console with an error:

> (node:9392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:9392) [DEP0018]
> DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
> the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
> Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I am looking for a solution by keeping the same code structure. Any help?

Comment: `isEmpty()` seems to be a Java function. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights,sorry, I forgot to clarify this thing, I am using node middleware **express-validator**, so `isEmty` Method originated from this middleware, check out these docs: [express-validator docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/index.html), thank you for the response .

Comment: I don't have much experience with `try catch` but it could be because `throw { code: 500, message: err }` is inside `passport.authenticate` which, I'm assuming, is an async function.

Comment: As it says in the error message: `This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block...`

Comment: It would be better to have `return res.status(500).json({message: err})`

Comment: @Daniel_Knights , I checked out the authenticate function, it is not an async function, all my functions are not async, I did not understand from where it gets it lol, for permeate solution, I made the same code that you gave to me now, thank you for our help :).